# Magento; Modifying a payment module changing name in "method" field

Tags: magento, payment

Modifying a payment module I'm not having any success changing the "payment name" that is placed in table `sales_flat_order_payment` in field "method".
For example if payment is check, it is populated with checkmo.
I've tried changing

`protected $_code  = '.........';` in payment.php with no success.

I'm guessing this name may need changing in multiple places?

I have researched this but any answers I can find are assuming I have the skill level to know how to duplicate or modify the extension.
magento ver 1.4.1.1

more info; I'm using a Western Union payment extension as a Bpay payment extension and that field method is used to SMS payment type to me (and it would be more elegant it said what it really was!)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have a separate payment method for  this. You can duplicate some existing method, and use your custom name.

Comment: Thanks Roman, this was EXACTLY my question, all the research I read said this "You can duplicate some existing method, and use your custom name". Where do I change the name to change this in method?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new payment module by duplicate one of your other payment module that closest matches what you are trying to do.

If you are trying to create a payment module for check then take a look at [create a new payment method](http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was hoping that instead of creating an entirely new module I could change the field name in one (or more places) and save building a module with (knowing my skills) many errors!